# Need to count the number of meta value of wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress, count

In this script i need to replace the $count variable with the number of post counts from the wordpress database:

```
<?php               
$state_query = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT meta_value AS state, COUNT(post_id) AS count
FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = 'state'
GROUP BY state ORDER BY count DESC"); 

$count = 50; //here i need to count the number of meta value of each post
$max = 100;
$scale = 1.0;

if ( !empty($max) ) { $percent = ($count * 100) / $max; } 
else { $percent = 0; }
?>

<?php if ($state_query) {
echo '<div class="cf">'; ?>
<?php foreach ($state_query as $st) 
echo ($percent * $scale);
?>              
<?php echo '</div>'; } ?>
```

Comment: Okay?  then why don't you go ahead and do that?

Comment: You can try to do you said, what's the problem?

Comment: I don't know how! if i put something like "$count = $state;" nothing happens. i have no idea how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$count = count($state_query);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `num_rows` like this

```
 $count = $wpdb->num_rows;
```

Comment: Now it shows me the number of ALL states in each row. But what i need is a row for each state with the number of posts who have this state as meta value.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring $wpdb as global and using it to execute an SQL query statement that returns a PHP object

May try this will help you lot.

```
$state_query = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT meta_value AS state, COUNT(post_id) AS count
FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = 'state'
GROUP BY state ORDER BY count DESC", OBJECT ); 


if($wpdb->num_rows)
{
    foreach ($state_query  as $result)
    {
    $count = $result->count;
    $max = 100;
    $scale = 1.0;
    }
}else{
    $count = 50; //here i need to count the number of meta value of each post
    $max = 100;
    $scale = 1.0;
}
```